# Specification Pattern vs (Fluent) Validation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

What is different between `Specification Pattern` and `(Fluent) Validation`? Are they similar?

```cs
// Specification
public class PremiumSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    private int cost;
    public PremiumSpecification(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }
 
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o) {
        return (o as Mobile).Cost >= this.cost; // HERE
    }
}
```

```cs
// Fluent Validation
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(customer => customer.Cost).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two examples are both doing validation, but are *stylistically* different.

The first uses inheritance and composition to to specify how the validation is performed, overriding a method to contain the validation logic. This is what most would consider an instance of *the* [Specification Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern).

The second uses a flatter structure (though it doesn't have to) and a `RuleFor()` specification that takes the validation logic as an expression to be executed against some subject. This isn't an instance of *the* Specification Pattern, but you can argue it is *a* specification pattern as the `RuleFor()` is a declarative statement (or specification) of what to do.

Though the latter has "Fluent" in it's name, that's for a different reason: it relies on the [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) style of programming. You can see that in your example because it uses [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) with the `RuleFor()` returning an object where `GreaterThanOrEqualTo()` is invoked immediately without assigning the result of `RuleFor()` to a temp variable.

EDIT: In practice, I've more often seen the specification pattern used in DDD because each specification can communicate an important domain validation or constraint very clearly just through the *name* of the specification. In practice, I've seen the second validation pattern more often used for user inputs prior to hydrating the domain.

This is totally anecdotal, and by no means an absolute rule.

Comment: In fact, apart from style, it does not matter which one we use? (especially in DDD)

Comment: You'd have to make that judgement, but at a high-level I'd say no it doesn't matter much. Use what fits your project. That said, *the* spec pattern appears, to on it's face, express your domain concepts a bit more clearly. Hope I've answered your question.